# solution to rotate log files

Tags: logs, logrotate

I am running a daemon process that will have to run indefinitely (a 'service' so to speak) and wish to log its output. A simple solution like:

```
./long-running-process > log.out &
```

... fails as the file `log.out`:

- soon exceeds the size that I can easily handle with a text editor like `emacs` or `vi`
- runs the risk of depleting free file system space.

To keep the size of the log file manageable I could use the `split` bash command:

```
./long-running-process | split -l 30000
```

This solution keeps the log files it creates manageable in size however it can run out of suffixes (`split: output file suffixes exhausted`) or, if the suffix space is huge, it may also deplete file system space.

So I am looking at a solution that will generate a number of log files, with each log file being manageable in size, and will also rotate amongst them so that there is a ceiling on the total disk space that will be claimed.

Is there such a solution available or do I have to implement it at the application level?

Comment: `logrotate` in another word ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To cut the logs

Apache project has a useful command `rotatelogs` designed to rotate input recieved via an input pipe Read [about rotatelogs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/rotatelogs.html)

Then there is also the `cronolog` better time handling. [Cronolog website](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cronolog/)

But if you are also rotating then it's worth considering logrotate, but logrotate will need a mechanism to trigger a new logfile, (send a signal,  restart the program, ...). This is where rotatelogs/cronolog might come in, if you are logging stdout and do not want to restart the process.

Comment: `rotatelogs` satisfies one of my requirements (generate log files that are manageable in size), but it too can fill the file system unless I combine `rotatelogs` with another process that automatically deletes log files that are older than, say, 3 days.

Comment: OK so I guess `rotatelogs` with a size limit and a chronological timestamp coupled with a cronjob to delete old log files is exactly what I need since I won't have to worry about restarting processes, I am just logging stdout and expect `rotatelogs` to transparently switch to new files as I've seen it does.

Answer (score 7):

Most modern Linux distros include a tool called `logrotate` which the OS then uses to maintain the `/var/log` directory. You can use it too. It is kicked off via `cron`, so if you want the logs rotated with a certain frequency then you need to setup a cronjob that runs atleast that frequently.

#### Examples

This will rotate the 2 files `access.log` & `error.log`, keeping at most 5 (current + 4 rotations). After relocating the current log file, `killall -HUP httpd` sends a "Hang Up" signal to the running daemon to trigger the creation of a new log file to start logging from this point on to the original named `access.log` and `error.log` files. This one will also rotate the log files if their size exceeds 100k.

```
   "/var/log/httpd/access.log" /var/log/httpd/error.log {
       rotate 5
       mail www@my.org
       size 100k
       sharedscripts
       postrotate
           /usr/bin/killall -HUP httpd
       endscript
   }
```

This one will rotate the log files under the directory `/var/log/news/*` montly, keeping 2 (current + 1). This set of rules will keep the logs in their original state, rather they will not be compressed (`.gz`) which is the default behavior.

```
   /var/log/news/* {
       monthly
       rotate 2
       olddir /var/log/news/old
       missingok
       postrotate
           kill -HUP `cat /var/run/inn.pid`
       endscript
       nocompress
   }
```

#### Do I have to send kill -HUP?

No this is not mandatory, only if your application requires it. This is what triggers your application to stop writing to the current log file (after it's been renamed from say `access.log` to `access.log.1`) and begin logging again to the original name, `access.log`.

```
/var/log/atop/atop.log {
    missingok
    weekly
    rotate 4 
    notifempty
    create 0600 root root
}
```

#### References

- [HowTo: The Ultimate Logrotate Command Tutorial with 10 Examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/logrotate-examples/)

Comment: Thanks but unless I 've missed something I prefer the solution with `rotatelogs` and a cronjob to delete old log files (which is the only part that `rotatelogs` doesn't provide out of the box). Seems like less configuration is needed (only a cronjob), I don't have to worry about sending signals or restarting processes (why should I?) and my scripts (except the cronjob) reside in the project's file system hierarchy meaning they are under `git` as well.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus - I showed 2 examples for triggering the recreation of the logs, but if your daemon is written correctly you don't need to do that either. The triggering is needed b/c when you move a file to a new name the filedescriptor is still the same, so the daemon will continue writing to the new name. The signal triggers the app to stop doing this and start writing to a new log file with the original name. There is no escaping this behavior, it's how FD's work. BTW, a HUP is not a restart, 2 completely different things!

Comment: It sounds like you're contradicting yourself.  You're saying -HUP is not always mandatory, but then you say "There is no escaping this behaviour".  Surely a daemon needs to know somehow when to start logging to the new file.

Comment: @Phil_1984_ - The requirement of explicitly calling a `kill -HUP` in the `postrotate` section. It comes down to implicitly relying on logrotate moving the file out of the way and the app picking up on this and starting a new file vs. having to explicitly trigger the creation of a new file after its been moved via sending the app a signal w/ a `kill -HUP`.

Answer (score 5):

for completeness sake i'd also like to mention the `copytruncate` option for `logrotate`:

> ```
>    copytruncate
>           Truncate the original log file to zero size in place after
>           creating a copy, instead of moving the old log file and
>           optionally creating a new one.  It can be used when some program
>           cannot be told to close its logfile and thus might continue
>           writing (appending) to the previous log file forever.
>          Note that there  is  a  very small  time  slice  between  copying
>           the  file  and truncating it, so some logging data might be lost.
>           When this option is used, the *create* option will have no effect,
>           as the old log file stays in place.
> ```

Comment: `copytruncate` doesnt need any package install.
So is an apt solution for logs other Apache's.

Comment: copytruncate does solve the issue of daemon signalling to open a new fd but introduces race conditions where log data may get "lost" (i.e. Never logged) during the rotation process.  You can't copy all data and truncate a file in a single atomic POSIX operation.  Normally this would be a deal breaker for anyone requiring log data consistency when writing to files.