# On what UNIX-like system / filesystem is the st_blocks field returned by stat() not a number of 512-byte units?

Tags: stat, portability, api

I always assumed the `st_blocks` field returned by `stat()`/`lstat()`... system calls  and which `du` uses to get the disk usage of files was expressed in 512 bytes units.

Checking the [POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/stat.h.html), I now see POSIX makes no guarantee for that. [The `perl` documentation for its own `stat()` function](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat) also warns against making that assumption.

In any case, as indicated by POSIX, that block size is not related to the `st_blksize` field returned by `stat()`, so has to be found elsewhere.

Checking the GNU `du` or GNU `find` source code, I see evidence HP/UX uses 1024 bytes units instead. GNU `find` adjusts its `-printf %b` output to always give a number of 512-byte units which is probably the source of my confusion.

Is there any other Unix-like system, still currently in use where `st_blocks` is not expressed in 512 byte units? Can that be filesystem dependant (as POSIX suggests)? I guess mounting an HP/UX NFS share could do it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`st_blksize` is called "the optimum I/O size" and unrelated to the units used for `st_blocks`. The optimum I/O size of course is filesystem specific. This is a result from the `fast filesystem` development from Berlekey in 1981/1982. Before, there was no optimum block size in the available filesystem

`st_blocks` is expressed in units of `DEV_BSIZE` that indeed is 1024 on HP-UX. `DEV_BSIZE` is a platform specific constant. Later, when `FFS` was renamed to `UFS`, there was a second filesystem in BSD UNIX with different behavior related to indirect blocks and that required this new `stat()` field. Before, `du` did just know the algorithm for indirect blocks from the filesystem.

If you run a HP-UX NFS fileserver and other NFS clients, you get wrong reports from the HP-UX NFS server for `df` unless HP did fix their problem during the past 15 years, where I had no access to recent versions of HP-UX. I know of no other UNIX with similar NFS related bugs.

BTW: up to NFSv3, NFS assumes a blocksize of 512 and HP would need to convert their NFS reports in the server. NFSv4 does not make that implicit assumption, but HP-UX still reports wrong numbers.

I know no other UNIX that is based on a 1024 `DEV_BSIZE`.

Comment: Thanks Jörg. I see GNU tools also refer to the `S_BLKSIZE` macro to determine the st_blocks size. Do you know more about the history of the `stat()` API? It seems to me `st_blksize` and `st_blocks` should have come in pair, and possibly they got misaligned at some point for historical reason?

Comment: It actually looks like `st_blksize` came first around BSD 4.1 in 1983, and st_blocks in BSD 4.2. They may not have been meant to be related.

Comment: `S_BLKSIZE` is Linux only and you are right, `st_blksize` is a result from developing `FFS` while `st_blocks` was added later to get better `du` results for files with indirect blocks and for holey files.

Comment: I don't see S_BLKSIZE mentioned anywhere in the Linux sources. GNU libc and uclibc define both S_BLKSIZE and DEV_BSIZE to 512 and musl only DEV_BSIZE. NetBSD also defines both. BSD 4.2 do define DEV_BSIZE to 512 independently of the BLKDEV_IOSIZE. I'm trying to figure out when HPUX added st_blocks and why it deviated from BSD. Earliest evidence I found so far is from 1985. None of the AT&T systems I looked (from research v1 -> v10 to SysIII -> SVR4.2  had st_blocks), I suppose POSIX took it from BSD

Comment: I see some header files in HPUX 5.1 (around the time its HFS file system was introduced) tape images as almost identical as the BSD4.2 one but with DEV_BSIZE changed from 512 to 1024. Also evidence there was collaboration with UCB. I guess that defines the minimum block size supported on the system.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: if I run `$ grep -Irl S_BLKSIZE /usr/include/`
at least on Ubuntu 20.04, I get this file: `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/stat.h`. EDIT: OK, alright – it's the GNU libc, not Linux kernel stictly speaking.